# Boostrapping data with Static html page with Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently using static pages (will move over to Jade soon) and I want to pass some information into my index.html when the first request is made.

I know this is possible with jade and I wanted to know what my options are if I use a static page?

For example, I need something like this:

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render(config.rootPath + '/public/index.html', {data: 'usernamehere'});
});
```

and in my index.html I have a script tag:

```
<script>
    var currentUser = data; <-- I know this will never work...
</script>
```

So should I make a call from my script tag to get the information or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider `express-expose`?

"Expose helpers and local variables to the client-side." See the [repo](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will use this (just put in an ajax call which I will strip out) :).